# Production Build - Impossible to load chunk-vendors

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

I am practicing with PWA application and stuck at my first production build. I am using a nginx configuration togheter with my project files deployed with docker + nginx.

I think my problem is located in nginx configurations because in a local environment with the same docker image is everything working like a charm.

My project is the default template of vue-cli with pwa, vuex and router activated / integrated.

```
server {
server_name www.domain.de;

client_max_body_size 100M;

listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location index.html {
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
}

location service-worker.js {
    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
}

location / {
    gzip_static on;
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8123$request_uri;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

}

Dockerfile for my project

```
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15.5-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Loading the website is not possible and you get a blank page with the following error messages in the console

Chrome:

```
GET https://www.domain.de/js/chunk-vendors.0a3c4518.js net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

Firefox:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://domain.de/js/chunk-vendors.0a3c4518.js”.
```

Comment: it could be related to caching assets. have you made any progress with this? I'm also working on a docker/nginx/vue project with a Django ReST Framework backend

Comment: nope.. i am still looking for a solution